# Convert String to java.util.Date in Java 8

Tags: java, android, multithreading, time

Currently I have a requirement to convert `String` to `java.util.Date`.
Found many tutorials to convert `string` to `Date` by using `java.text.SimpleDateFormatter`. But my concern in this `SimpleDateFormatter` is not thread safe.
Is there any possibility to convert `string` to `java.util.Date` by using java.time package in Java 8. Since `java.time` package classes are thread safe.

Comment: Java 8 and Android in the same question?

Comment: The fact that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe is not a problem. Just create a new instance each time you need it. *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*

Comment: I am not sure, whats wrong in this question to vote -1?

Comment: Are you definitely using it in a multi-threaded environment? If not, you don't need to worry about it being threadsafe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question about `java.time` from Java SE 8:

You could use:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(someDateString);
```

and to convert it to date you could use:

```
Instant instant = date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Date res = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: Here `parse()` method return type is `LocaleDate`, but I need `java.util.Date`

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti added conversion